# How to append text to my file so it adds new content instead of overwrite

Tags: c#

Everything is working until I register a new user and click "save" it overwrites whats in the text file with the new info, I would like to add a new line and start to add the contents array again. I know there is an "append" function but I've tried many things and cant seem to get it to work with my current way of writing to a file.

```
    private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       string[] contents = new string[4];
    contents[0] = "Name: " + txtName.Text;
    contents[1] = "Address: " + txtAddress.Text;
    contents[2] = "Phone: " + txtPhone.Text;
    contents[3] = "Blood Type: " + cmbBloodType.SelectedItem.ToString();

    System.IO.File.WriteAllLines( @"C:\Users\Ben\Documents\C#\Final\Bloodbank\BloodBank\bin\Debug\Bloodbank.txt", contents);

    }
```

Comment: I've tried to use the append function and nothing was working so i returned it to what did work to write to the file 1 time but now with what I have i just cant seem to append new information to it and i'm assuming it is something incredibly simple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's because your content is an array, so you have to join this array in one string like:

```
    System.IO.File.AppendAllText(@"C:\Users\Ben\Documents\C#\Final\Bloodbank\BloodBank\bin\Debug\Bloodbank.txt", string.Join(Environment.NewLine, contents));
```

Comment: There is `File.AppendAllLines` method as well. No need to manually join the lines.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `File.AppendAllText()`?
Here is an example:

```
File.AppendAllText(@"C:\Users\Ben\Documents\C#\Final\Bloodbank\BloodBank\bin\Debug\Bloodbank.txt", "content" + Environment.NewLine);
```

Comment: no but i'm 99% sure that i cant do it that way because having contents in double quotes makes that my "text" im putting into the file

Comment: @user3485895 That was just an example. The second parameter is whatever text you want to append to the file, `contents` in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Edited Code: When you go to save your file, try:

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Text.StringBuilder stringBuilder = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
    stringBuilder.AppendLine("Name: " + txtName.Text);
    stringBuilder.AppendLine("Address: " + txtAddress.Text);
    stringBuilder.AppendLine("Phone: " + txtPhone.Text);
    stringBuilder.AppendLine("Blood Type: " + cmbBloodType.SelectedItem.ToString());

    System.IO.File.AppendAllText(@"C:\Users\Ben\Documents\C#\Final\Bloodbank\BloodBank\bin\Debug\Bloodbank.txt", stringBuilder.ToString() + Environment.NewLine);
}
```

That should append the text to the end of the file. The official documentation can be found here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143356(v=vs.110).aspx

Hope this helps!

Comment: I dont receive any errors when starting up the program with your suggestion but when I click "register"  this is what shows up in the text file "System.String[]" would you have the slightest idea as to why it is saving that instead of the contents of my text boxes?

Comment: The best thing to do is put everything in a `StringBuilder`. I'm going to update my answer to reflect that.